# Docker, microservices & network

Tags: docker, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I'm buiding microservice architecture with docker. Eureka registers all services [image]

but as soon as i'm clicking at any link -> couldn't access the site. What did I do wrong?

Basically, i'm using internal network and my containers don't have access to internet and that's sad. That's said, I'm using windows 10 home(i should upgrade to pro, i think) and docker desktop.

Comment: Please add more details about error and software versions

Comment: Okay, basically I'm using internal network and my docker container's don't have internet access. I'm using Docker Desktop (for windows).

Comment: Which links, and which site are you taking about?